# Connect to remote GridGain node from Java Application

Tags: java, gridgain

I am trying to connect to an existing grid of GridGain nodes configured as computing nodes, however I haven't managed to find a way to connect to the cluster without having to programmatically start and in-memory node.

I even tried to replicate the config in my Java app but still no progress:

```
List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<String>();
addressList.add("127.0.0.1:47500..47509");

GridTcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder gridTcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder = new GridTcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
gridTcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder.setAddresses(addressList);

GridTcpDiscoverySpi gridTcpDiscoverySpi = new GridTcpDiscoverySpi();
gridTcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(gridTcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder);

Collection<GridNode> remoteNodes = gridTcpDiscoverySpi.getRemoteNodes();
```

Is there a way to connect to an existing grid without having to start an in-memory node?

**EDIT:**

I've also tried to connect to running nodes by using the **UUID** and again no luck:

```
Grid grid = GridGain.grid(UUID.fromString("186FFB45-2686-4A69-BAF0-791E4C0B5E69"));
```

Also what I'm trying to achieve is to make a remote computation with a Java Future:

```
 GridCompute gridCompute = gridNode.grid().compute();
 AsyncObject asyncObject = new AsyncObject();
 GridFuture gf = gridCompute.call(asyncObject);
```

Where **AsyncObject** is a class that implements the **Callable** interface and returns the sum of two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have GridGain node connect to a cluster without participating in data caching. Take a look at [Client Node vs Data Node](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Client+Node+vs+Data+Node) documentation on GridGain Wiki.

Comment: So from what I've read there, whatever you do you need to start an in-memory node to connect to an existing grid? And configure it to be either client node  or data node? Was trying to find if there is an API that allows this without having to start and additional node, but this will suffice for now.